# adding two variables result in Nan

Tags: javascript

i have been trying to add the two different variables shown in the code below, but no matter what i do it results is Nan, is there anything wrong i am doing here? i have tried to play around it for a while but i can't find anything wrong with my code!

```
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            function showEstimate() {
                            switch (document.getElementById("cboCar").value) {
                            case "A":
                            document.getElementById("imgCar").src= "images/Accord.jpg";
                            carPrice = document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value;
                            break;
                            case "C":
                            document.getElementById("imgCar").src= "images/Civic.jpg";
                            carPrice = document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value;
                            break;
                            }  // end of switch block. 
                            //here, the UI has done processing cars pics 
                            //display the price for cars
                            document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value=  "$" + carPrice;
                             // end of the function named



                            {
                               var vchkSt= (300.99).toFixed();
                               var vchkLe= (750.99).toFixed();
                               var vchkGps= (1600.00).toFixed();
                               var tTotal = 0;
                               carPrice = Number(document.getElementById("txtBasePr").value);


                                if (document.getElementById("chkSt").checked)
                                tTotal +=  parseFloat(carPrice) + parseFloat(vchkSt);

                                if (document.getElementById("chkLe").checked )
                                tTotal +=  parseFloat(carPrice) + parseFloat(vchkLe);

                                if (document.getElementById("chkGps").checked ==true )
                                tTotal +=  parseFloat(carPrice) + parseFloat(vchkGps);


                                //displaying the total
                                document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value = "$" + tTotal;
                                }   
                                 }   // end of function showEstimate

                                </script>
```

Comment: wrong: `(300.99).toFixed;` and `Number(carPrice = document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value);`

Comment: did you check what `carPrice` is? If getElementById() fails (e.g. wrong id), then carPrice is going to be a null.

Comment: I am assinging carPrice as value of getElememtbyId("txtEstpr")

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling the `toFixed` function, instead you're assigning the function to `chkSt`, `chkLe`, and `chkGps`:

```
var chkSt= (300.99).toFixed;
var chkLe= (750.99).toFixed;
var chkGps= (1600.00).toFixed;
```

Instead it should be:

```
var chkSt= (300.99).toFixed();
var chkLe= (750.99).toFixed();
var chkGps= (1600.00).toFixed();
```

Also

```
Number(carPrice = document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value);
```

Doesn't make any sense. There's no need to wrap the assignment in the `Number` function. It looks like you're trying to assign the value as a number to `carPrice`, which would be done simply as:

```
carPrice = +document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value;
```

or

```
carPrice = Number(document.getElementById("txtEstPr").value);
```

Furthermore, you're reassigning `tTotal` with each subsequent checkbox. You should probably use:

```
if (document.getElementById("chkSt").checked) {
    tTotal +=  parseFloat(carPrice) + parseFloat(chkSt);
    //     ^
}
```

with `var tTotal = 0` to initialize the variable.

Comment: I am still getting same issue

Comment: @sunnybouy91, I recommend that you invest some time into improving your question. Take the time to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) on a service such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), or even within your question using the [snippet feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).